# Access methods of class when calling ThreadPoolExecutor in another method

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrent.futures

I have a method that asynchronously retrieves some data and has to call other method to store that data. I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to get that data.

The class is something like this:

```
class A:
    [...]
    def update_balance(self, exchange_name, balance):
        if balance is not None:
            self.exchanges[exchange_name].balance = balance

    def __balance_getter(ex, this):
            balance = ex.get_balance()
            if balance is not None:
                update_balance(ex.api.name, balance) ---> Can't call update_balance. I have no ref of self

    def retrieve_all_balances(self, exchange_list):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(self.__balance_getter, exchange_list)
```

How could I pass to `__balance_getter()` a reference of `self` so I can call `self.update_balance()`?

Thanks

Comment: Your `__balance_getter` is defined inside a function that has a `self` defined so it *does* have a reference to `self`...

Comment: you are right. this example is not what I wanted to do. Let me change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite `__balance_getter` so that it just returns information. Rewrite `retrieve_all_balances` to create a list of futures, then send the result(s) to `update_balance` as each future completes.

```
class A:
    [...]
    def update_balance(self, exchange_name, balance):
        if balance is not None:
            self.exchanges[exchange_name].balance = balance

    def __balance_getter(ex, this):
            balance = ex.get_balance()
            return (ex.api.name, balance)
#            if balance is not None:
#                update_balance(ex.api.name, balance) ---> Can't call update_balance. I have no ref of self

    def retrieve_all_balances(self, exchange_list):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(self.__balance_getter, arg) for arg in exchange_list]
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                name,balance = future.result()
                self.update_balance(name,balance)
```

Can't really test if this solves your problem as you didn't provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).